# Node install fail (Linux Mint 20.1). "while trying to load binding.gyp"

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

My node install broke yesterday, after syncing my project to my office Mac (am guessing something's crawled in and crunched something).

I've spent the last day trying everything I can find on the Intertubes (reinstalling node, npm, downgrading, upgrading, deleting project's /node_modules, jsconfig.json and yarn lock files), all to no avail.

Hoping that a Node/Linux guru can pick out what's failing from this error chain (it's remained consistent throughout all my efforts above).

Any ideas/help/thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

-Chris

---

```
chris@chris-mint:~/Projects/fz-apollo$ npm install
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:40999/46c7c7b2-9a5d-4500-a20e-85ccbea53745
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
npm WARN deprecated @kazupon/vue-i18n-loader@0.5.0: WARNING: If you would like to use @kazupon/vue-i18n-loader that is released new features and bug fixes, you need to install @intlify/vue-i18n-loader.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()

> node@11.15.0 preinstall /home/chris/Projects/fz-apollo/node_modules/node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38979/98b4e5e9-8a20-44d1-ae54-fec8c64ef3e8
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:37189/259c9155-7ced-4f31-980a-579ac3626c32
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
+ node-linux-x64@11.15.0
added 1 package in 0.537s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

> deasync@0.1.21 install /home/chris/Projects/fz-apollo/node_modules/deasync
> node ./build.js

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38235/35c10566-9638-4984-8f25-7d2afbbd17b6
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
`linux-x64-node-11` exists; testing
Problem with the binary; manual build incoming
stdout=
err=null
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43577/7d006c68-2d31-441d-8398-e6ceefc5b286
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:46097/67c47b61-b1a5-48dd-bc41-97b745e7fb56
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
gyp: Call to 'node -p "require('node-addon-api').include"' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:255:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-65-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/chris/Projects/fz-apollo/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/chris/Projects/fz-apollo/node_modules/deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Build failed
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! deasync@0.1.21 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.21 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/chris/.npm/_logs/2021-02-10T13_05_10_494Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...


chris@chris-mint:~/Projects/fz-apollo$ node -v
v12.20.1
chris@chris-mint:~/Projects/fz-apollo$ npm -v
6.14.10
```

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you mean by “syncing to your Mac”. But you can see in your debug output that some of the modules think they are Mac versions of the modules (see where it says “Darwin”).  If you have your source code in git, blow everything away and revert to the last working commit.  If you physically copied the files to your Mac, did some work, then copied them back, and you have no way to restore the last working copy... then, well... that’s why you should be using source control and a repeatable build process that’s backed by source control.

Comment: Yes, had gone via git to my office Mac and then back -- good catch with the Mac versions, somehow I hadn't seen those bits. 

Many thanks, will sort it now :-)

Comment: Sometimes just requires a new set of eyes. If I had a dollar for every time I’ve spent a day chasing something someone else saw at a glance, I’d be a rich man. Good luck.

Comment: Blow everything away, revert to last known working version from git? That should get your environment working again. Then you can merge the updates one by one that you made on your mac.

Comment: I've gone back through several levels of known working commits, taking from github... Sadly, whatever has borked things continues to do so.

I really wish it was easier to "completely" remove node, npm, etc. and just do a fresh install. Seems silly to waste so much time on something that should be easy/straightforward.

Comment: Yep. Completely agree.Side note, I normally do development on one machine and deploy to "Dev" on a different machine for this reason. Deploying to "Dev" bootstraps the entire environment from scratch.  Languages like golang make this pretty easy.  node, a bit more complex.  You could try creating another linux machine (e.g. via lxd) and build up your node environment from scratch, using only last known working code.

Comment: Completely removed all node, npm and nvm files and reinstalled from scratch. Errors are still as before. I'm going to install a Mint (my desktop of choice at mo) VM on Virtualbox and see if I can recreate everything there -- wasting waaaay too much time on something that I don't really grokk.

Comment: Took about an hour to setup a new Mint vm and install everything, clone from github and have running with zero errors. Have a few more ideas on things to try for fixing the Node+project on the main Mint box, but good enough for the moment.